# Terraform Resource attribute not being removed when passing in empty values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am working with a GCP Cloud Composer resource and added in a dynamic block to create an attribute for the resource to set allowed_ip_ranges which can be used as an IP filter for accessing the Apache Airflow Web UI.

I was able to get the allowed ranges setup and can update them in place to new values also.

If I attempt to pass in a blank list I am expecting the IP address(es) to be removed as attributes for the resource but Terraform seems to think that no changes are needed.

There is probably something wrong in my code but I am not sure what exactly I would need to do. Does it involve adding in a conditional expression to the for_each loop in the dynamic block?

Child module main.tf

```
    web_server_network_access_control {
      dynamic "allowed_ip_range" {
        for_each = var.allowed_ip_range
        content {
          value       = allowed_ip_range.value["value"]
          description = allowed_ip_range.value["description"]
        }
      }
    }
```

Child module variables.tf

```
variable "allowed_ip_range" {
  description = "The IP ranges which are allowed to access the Apache Airflow Web Server UI."
  type        = list(map(string))
  default     = []
}
```

Parent module terraform.tfvars

```
allowed_ip_range                 = [
    {
    value = "11.0.0.2/32"
    description = "Test dynamic block 1"
    },
]
```

Comment: Not sure, maybe you need the map part also with values set to empty strings, i.e., `[{value = "", description=""}]`.

Comment: very much interested in an answer. I just recreated your scenario using the docker provider and dynamic blocks of Labels. Seems change is picked up, adding and removing sets of Labels, but it is not possible to remove the last one. If the array is empty it is just disregarded. We can fill it with empty strings, but that is ugly. Tried using a null_resource and a depends_on, but also could not get that to work. Leaving this here for reference.

Comment: @Chai Currently it seems like it is due to how the provider handles passing in a blank list. In some instances a blank list will be inferred as a request to not do anything/not edit anything. I still need to try out the suggestion from Marko above but check out this link in the meantime. https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/unable-to-remove-resource-attribute-that-was-provisioned-with-terraform/24701/2?u=rk92

Comment: I tried out Markos suggestion in my docker provider and it then return a set of 1 label `{ "" : "" }` . Will read up on the info thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value in your `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "allowed_ip_range" {
  description = "The IP ranges which are allowed to access the Apache Airflow Web Server UI"
  type        = list(map(string))
  default = [
    {
      value       = "0.0.0.0/0"
      description = "Allows access from all IPv4 addresses (default value)"
    },
    {
      value       = "::0/0"
      description = "Allows access from all IPv6 addresses (default value)"
    },
  ]
}
```

And when you will delete your variable from `terraform.tfvars`, you will have the default values